# UWP: how to prevent ToggleButton unchecked once it is checked

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app, togglebutton

I have a very quick question. I am using toggle button to switch between 2 options (it can be more but for simplicity, let's just say two buttons) and once the button is checked, I don't want it to be unchecked unless it select the other option (ie. one option must be selected all the time).

In WPF, I used to handle **PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown** to prevent the toggle button to go unchecked. But it doesn't seem to be available in UWP.

Here is my code so far:

```
//in XAML
<ToggleButton x:Name="tbtnCash" Grid.Column="0" Content="CASH" IsChecked="True" IsDoubleTapEnabled="False" IsHoldingEnabled="False" IsRightTapEnabled="False" Padding="20" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Tapped="tbtnCash_Tapped"></ToggleButton>

<ToggleButton x:Name="tbtnCard" Grid.Column="1" Content="CARD" IsDoubleTapEnabled="False" IsHoldingEnabled="False" IsRightTapEnabled="False" Padding="20" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Tapped="tbtnCard_Tapped"></ToggleButton>


//In code
private void tbtnCash_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;

    tbtnCash.IsChecked = true;
    tbtnCard.IsChecked = false;
}

private void tbtnCard_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;

    tbtnCash.IsChecked = false;
    tbtnCard.IsChecked = true;
}
```

Now, if I tapped the **Cash button** two or three times (quickly), the **Cash button** will go unchecked. It seems that the `e.Handled = true;` has no effect. Can you help me?

Thanks!

Comment: I would try something with setting *IsHitTestVisible* depending on your needs (for example bind to property which checks all buttons and combine with current one's checked state).

Comment: Why don't you use radio buttons instead of toggle buttons?

Comment: What about IsEnabled? I think it should solve everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we tapped Cash button two times quickly, the Tap event will be fired once. The second time tap the `ToggleButton`, it only change the state of the `ToggleButton` from checked to unchecked.

As a workaround, you should be able to add the Click event to the `ToggleButton`.  And in the Click event, we should be able to set the IsChecked property as in Tap event.

When we tap the `ToggleButton` once, the Click event will be fired and then the Tap event will be fired.
If we tap the `ToggleButton` twice, the Click event will be fired twice.

For example:

```
private void tbtnCash_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Tap is fired!");
    e.Handled = true;
    tbtnCash.IsChecked = true;
    tbtnCard.IsChecked = false;
}

private void tbtnCard_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
    tbtnCash.IsChecked = false;
    tbtnCard.IsChecked = true;
}

private void tbtnCash_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Click is fired!");
    tbtnCash.IsChecked = true;
    tbtnCard.IsChecked = false;
}

private void tbtnCard_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    tbtnCash.IsChecked = false;
    tbtnCard.IsChecked = true;
}
```